# Continuity of functions examples

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to give explicit examples of two functions

$f$: [0,1]$\in\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g$: (1,2]$\in\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ and $g$ are continuous,

but the function $h$: [0,2]$\in\mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x)=$$\ \begin{cases}f(x)&x\in[0,1]\\g(x)&x\in(1,2]\end{cases}$.

Cannot use anything to do with limits. I could come up with functions for $f$ and $g$ that fit but I'm not sure if there is anything that will help me so it fits $h$ besides guess and check?

Comment: How can you not use anything with limits? The very definition of continuity uses limits.

Comment: Right now our definition of continuous is f:D-->R is continuous if for all a in D and all positive epsilon, there exists a positive delta such that for all x in R mod(x-a)<delta implies mod(f(x)-f(a))<epsilon

Answer (score 3):

I think (if I understand your question) you just need $h$ to be discontinuous at $x=1$ (since it is clearly continuous on $[0,1]$ and $(1,2]$). In other words you need $f(1)\neq \lim_{x\to1^{+}}g(x)$. There are loads of options, eg. $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=2$.

Comment: Actually $g(1)$ is not defined. So the condition is $f(1)\ne \lim_{x\to 1^+} g(x).$

Comment: Good point, have edited!